# Ignore data annotation (e.g. maxlength) in code migrations

Tags: c#, entity-framework, ef-code-first, database-migration, entity-framework-migrations

I have code-first with data annotations, I want to apply MaxLength(50) to a field or Required but this must not affect database when I create new migrations. It is possible to achieve this ? 
The reason: I need this for form validation on input/send but this must not affect database.
**Used Technologies:**
Databse: SQL SERVER 2016
V.S. 2017
MVC 5
Many thanks

Comment: yes, you can do this, create a DTO class, define properties with data annotation in this DTO class and remove data annotations from model class. Another approach would be to handle validation at client side.

Comment: I kenw DTO but I want to avoit this. I have more than 200 Entities and some entities have more than 50 columns..

Comment: All the more reason to use DTO/ViewModel. [Separation of Concerns](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Separation_of_concerns). Tools like automapper can ease the process.